# On the dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $U, V, W$ be finite dimensional $\mathbb KG$-modules. Assume that the sequence of homomorphisms
$0 \to U \to V\to W\to 0$ is left exact but not right exact. Then, $\dim V \leq dim U + \dim W.$
How to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question about vector spaces, and the action of $G$ is irrelevant.

The sequence $0\to U\to V\to W$ is exact. This means that the image of the
map $U\to V$ (call it $f$) is the kernel of the map $V\to W$ (call it $g$)
and that $f$ is injective. By the rank-nullity formula, $\dim \ker g=\dim V-\dim g(V)$.
As $f$ is injective, $\dim\ker g=\dim f(U)=\dim U$. Then
$$\dim V=\dim U+\dim g(V)\le\dim U+\dim W$$
since $g(V)\subseteq W$.